# clang 10 & OpenMP on range-based for error (docs say should be ok)

Tags: c++, c++17, openmp, clang++

I am testing clang 10.0 on an c++17 & OpenMP project and get errors when `#pragma omp parallel for` is used on range-based for.

Release notes for clang 10, in the [OpenMP Support in Clang](https://releases.llvm.org/10.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#openmp-support-in-clang) section, say quite clearly:

- Added support for range-based loops.

When I compile a MWE with `clang++-10 -fopenmp -std=c++17` (see https://godbolt.org/z/fdTeMo for online compiler):

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::vector<int> ii{0,11,22,33,44,55,66};
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int& i: ii){
        std::cerr<<i<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get:

```
<source>:6:5: error: statement after '#pragma omp parallel for' must be a for loop

    for(int& i: ii){

    ^

1 error generated.

Compiler returned: 1
```

What's up?

Comment: It looks as if you are not using OpenMP 5.0 (even if you are using a clang version that _supports_ its new features). Have you tried explicitly selecting OpenMP 5.0 (where the support for range-based for loops were added)? `clang++-10 -fopenmp -fopenmp-version=50 -std=c++17`.

Comment: @dfri Yup, that works: https://godbolt.org/z/Erax36

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for range-based for loops was added to OpenMP 5.0, and, as is also described in the [Clang 10 Release Notes](https://releases.llvm.org/10.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#openmp-support-in-clang) that you link to, you need to explicitly use the `-fopenmp-version=50` option to activate support for it:

> #### OpenMP Support in Clang
>
> Use `-fopenmp-version=50` option to activate support for OpenMP 5.0.

Thus, if we expand you compilation command to `clang++-10 -fopenmp -fopenmp-version=50 -std=c++17`, the OMP pragma accepts the range based for loop that follows it.

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/8381eG).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am used to gcc which does not require OpenMP version specification. AFAIK it formally supports OpenMP 4.5 but takes range-based parallel loop without an error.